# How to use key and values from a hashmap in ArrayAdapter?

Tags: android

I have a hashmap with key, value pairs example :-

(msisdn,value)

43664xxxxxxx,2
43665xxxxxxx,3

now I want to display this information in a ListView but I don't know
how to feed the data to an ArrayAdapter from the Hashmap ?

HERE IS MY ADAPTER, note I want to replace myList with data from the
Hashmap a concatentated key+value.

1. Pass the above hashmap to the adapter, replacing myList with the
   hashmap

   `adapter=new
       ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,myList);
       setListAdapter(adapter);`

thanks

Without HASHMAP

```
packagelistmodified.org;

importjava.util.Arrays;
importjava.util.ArrayList;
importjava.util.HashMap;
importjava.util.List;
importjava.util.Map;

importandroid.app.ListActivity;
importandroid.os.Bundle;
importandroid.os.Handler;
importandroid.os.Message;
importandroid.view.View;
importandroid.widget.AdapterView;
importandroid.widget.ArrayAdapter;
importandroid.widget.ListView;
importandroid.widget.TextView;
importandroid.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;
importandroid.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener;
importandroid.view.GestureDetector;
importandroid.view.MotionEvent;
importandroid.widget.Toast;




publicclasslistmodifiedextendsListActivityimplements
OnGestureListener{
publicArrayList<String>myList=new
ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(items));
privateTextViewselection;//MAIN.xml
publicArrayAdapter<String>adapter;//myadapter
publicOnItemLongClickListeneritemDelListener;
privateGestureDetectorgestureScanner;
publicintlongClickedItem=0;//checkiflongClickisselectedor
not
privateStringitemSelected;//fordeletefunction
privatestaticfinalbyteUPDATE_LIST=100;
publicAdapterView<?>parent;//usedbyOnLitemLongClickListener
publicintposition;

//tieitemstoanarraylistcalledmyList
publicstaticString[]items={"lorem","ipsum","dolor",
"sit","amet",
"consectetuer","adipiscing","elit","morbi","vel",
"ligula","vitae","arcu","aliquet","mollis",
"etiam","vel","erat","placerat","ante",
"porttitor","sodales","pellentesque","augue","purus"};

@Override
publicvoidonCreate(Bundleicicle){
super.onCreate(icicle);

OnItemLongClickListeneritemDelListener=new
OnItemLongClickListener(){

//@Override
publicbooleanonItemLongClick(AdapterView<?>parent,Viewarg1,
intposition,longarg3){
//TODOAuto-generatedmethodstub
itemSelected=parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
adapter.remove(itemSelected);
Toast.makeText(listmodified.this,"positionis:"+position,
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
myList.remove(this);//removethecurrentobject,positionthrows
anexception
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


returnfalse;
}};

setContentView(R.layout.main);


//DEFINEMYOWNVIEWTIETOARRAYLISTmyListWHICHCONTAINSSTRINGS
adapter=new
ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,myList);
setListAdapter(adapter);

//AVIEWOFTHELISTNECESSARYFORDELETION

selection=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.selection);


//PARTOFLONGCLICKSELECTEDCODE
//CALLSIMPLEMENTEDMETHODS-detectgesturescheckingmylistitems
gestureScanner=newGestureDetector(this);
getListView().setOnTouchListener(newView.OnTouchListener(){
@Override
publicbooleanonTouch(Viewv,MotionEventevent){
returngestureScanner.onTouchEvent(event);
}
});

//UPDATEVIEWDELETEWHENONLONGCLICKISPRESSED
getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(itemDelListener);

}


//LISTITEMPRESSCHECKING
publicvoidonListItemClick(ListViewparent,Viewv,
intposition,longid){
selection.setText(myList.get(position));
//checktoseeifLONGCLICKISPRESSED
if(longClickedItem!=-1){
Toast.makeText(listmodified.this,"Ashortclickdetected",
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
longClickedItem=0;
}

//IMPLEMENTEDBYGESTURE
@Override
publicbooleanonDown(MotionEventarg0){
//TODOAuto-generatedmethodstub
returnfalse;
}


@Override
publicbooleanonFling(MotionEvente1,MotionEvente2,float
velocityX,
floatvelocityY){
//TODOAuto-generatedmethodstub
returnfalse;
}


//CHECKSONLONGPRESSEVENTSSETLONGPRESSTO-1,
//COOLICANUSETHISTOSEEIFALONGCLICKWASSELECTEDLATERON

@Override
publicvoidonLongPress(MotionEvente){
//TODOAuto-generatedmethodstub
Toast.makeText(listmodified.this,"Alongclickdetected",
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


if(e.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
{

longClickedItem=-1;

}

}


@Override
publicbooleanonScroll(MotionEvente1,MotionEvente2,float
distanceX,
floatdistanceY){
//TODOAuto-generatedmethodstub
returnfalse;
}


@Override
publicvoidonShowPress(MotionEvente){
//TODOAuto-generatedmethodstub

}


@Override
publicbooleanonSingleTapUp(MotionEvente){
//TODOAuto-generatedmethodstub
returnfalse;
}
privateHandlerupdateListHandler=newHandler(){
@Override
publicvoidhandleMessage(Messagemsg){
switch(msg.what){
caseUPDATE_LIST:
intposition=msg.arg1;
myList.remove(position);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
Toast.makeText(listmodified.this,"OnSingleTapUp",
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
break;

}
;
};
};


}
```

Answer (score 6):

> I don't know how to feed the data to an ArrayAdapter from the Hashmap ?

Use `new ArrayList<String>(myHashMap.keySet())`, assuming `myHashMap` is a `HashMap<String, Something>`.

Comment: Took me a while to find what he wanted to display, but it's the key and the value: "I want to replace myList with data from the Hashmap a concatentated key+value."

Comment: Hi, the code I posted includes items of type String, and it is part of myList   

publicArrayList<String>myList=new 
ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(items)); 


and my ArraryAdapter is using this ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,myList); 
setListAdapter(adapter); 

but if I have an hash which contains key value pairs which I want to pass these instead of a simple string array  this is were I am having problems

Comment: @user803271: You don't "pass them". Either fill into the `ArrayList` *precisely* what you want to have appear, or extend `ArrayAdapter`, override `getView()`, and handle populating the list rows yourself. Somewhere, you are going to need to concatenate your strings -- whether you do that up front or on a per-row basis is up to you.

Comment: One more question when I declare a test HashMap it seems only to work as static 

private static final Map<Integer, String> myHashMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>(); 
    static { 
     myHashMap.put(1, "one"); 
     myHashMap.put(2, "two"); 
    }                                                                and I am unable to access the HashMap outside of the brackets. So new ArrayList<String>(MyHashMap.KeySet()) fails as MyHashMap cannot be resolved ... ?

Comment: public class MyClass 
{ 
     private Map<Integer, String> myHashMap; 


     public MyClass() 
     { 
          myHashMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>(); 
          myHashMap.put(1, "one"); 
          myHashMap.put(2, "two"); 
     } 



}

Comment: So I have something like this now 
public class listmodified extends ListActivity implements OnGestureListener {
//public ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(items));
 public Map<Integer, String> myHashMap; 
      {
          String Result="";
          myHashMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>(); 
           myHashMap.put(1, "one"); 
           myHashMap.put(2, "two"); 
           myHashMap.keySet().toArray();
           myHashMap.values().toArray();
         Result = ": + myHashMap.keySet().toArray() + myHashMap.values().toArray()";}How do iterate over the HashMap?